# I am trying to learn use of tuple in python in shell (jupyter notebook) /(anaconda prompt) , from online courses . I got stuck on tuple part

Tags: python, tuples, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, immutability

My instructor said tuple is list type and it is immutable.
but i tried code

```
>>>tuple1=[3,4,5,6]
>>>tuple1[1]=44
>>>tuple1
[3,44,5,6]



>>>list[3]=66

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment

>>> s=['hi','hello',33]
>>> list[1]='hitech'
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment
```

this was output. but I don't know why it is not showing

```
 <Error>
```

Comment: I thrown question directly from my practice. I am not sure that whether my code is in right direction to express my problem. but simply I was expecting <Error> at 4th line . why it is not there?

Comment: Your variable is called `tuple`, but that does not actually make it a tuple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instructor is right about a tuple being immutable but your "tuple" is actually a list (with square brackets).

```
>>> tuple1 = [3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> type(tuple1)
<class 'list'>
>>> tuple1 = (3, 4, 5, 6)
>>> type(tuple1)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> tuple1[1] = 44
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

The other problem is that you are trying to get an item from the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) not an actual list.

```
>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> my_list[3] = 66
>>> my_list
[1, 2, 3, 66]
>>> type(list)
<class 'type'>
>>> list[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your support it helped me a lot. btw what is built-in list ? I got idea of actual list - like in abbove explanation it is my_list.

Comment: In the example above, `my_list` has a type of `list`. It is a [built-in data structure in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) and because of that you shouldn't ever use `list` as a variable name. You can create a list in a bunch of ways, `list('123')`, `list(range(5))`, `[x**2 for x in range(5)]`, `[1, 2, 3]`, etc. For more information, you can try looking at the official [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).